# Is it possible to insert an image in comments? if the answer is "yes", then how?

Tags: support, comment, images

Is it possible to insert an image in comments? if the answer is "yes", then how?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Not possible: [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/is-it-possible-to-add-images-to-comments)

Comment: for example in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882836/vanishing-of-local-cohomology-and-primary-decomposition/882846#882846  i wanted to import a pic. of the new edition of book, for thebowler_300 to see if i am right about question?

Comment: You can put the picture in your answer, if you think it's important.

Comment: thank you again but it is not part of answer

Comment: Well, then just [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/will-images-included-in-a-comment-remain-available) to the image as described in what I linked to.

Comment: $\style{ display: inline-block; background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/UFoAJ.jpg?s=48&g=1) no-repeat center;}{\phantom{\Rule{48px}{48px}{0px}}}$ it is possible. (this at least render properly in firefox28).

Comment: how??????????????!!!!!!!!!

Comment: the `\style` command from MathJAX extension HTML. Move your mouse over the icon, right click over it to see the commands. I don't recommend using this at all as I don't believe this works correctly over all browser. I just want to show there are a lot of hidden possibilities in the technology SE is using.

Comment: thanks. about your  last statement, I agree.

Comment: @achillehui Based from [here](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/SXjY3rQXOzc),  do you see [*this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmlhh.jpg) in the below comment? If not, how would one use the \style command on mobile?

Comment: $\lower{30pt}{\style{height: 100px; content: url(i.stack.imgur.com/Ttmig.png)}{ {~\over~}\over}} $

Comment: @TymaGaidash I didn't see anything. If you are able to see the image in my comment posted at 2014. Move the mouse over that image, right click and `Select Math As > Tex Commands` to see the mathjax needed to display the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most you can do is provide a link to the image. Comments are not meant to take up a lot of space, and one thing that pictures tend to do is take up space. However, it's common enough that comments may contain the need to reference images in order to help clarify or expand on the point they are making. So simply linking to the images is perfectly fine.

If you do not yet have the image uploaded online, you can still upload it directly through us. Just open a post editor (if you didn't ask the question or yet write an answer on the page you're commenting on, you'll have one already open at the bottom of the page, otherwise you can use the Ask Question button in the top right), and click on the Image button on the toolbar. You can then upload to imgur through us, and then copy the URL from the post body to use in your comment as you see fit.