# Posting a graphic in comments.

Tags: feature-request, comment, images

This post is in reference to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804490/simplifying-an-infinite-fraction#comment5782279_2804490) comment .

The sentiment which both I and the user who commented (and a few others in the MSE community perhaps) share is the possibility of being able to post graphics in comments . This would help in situations where one would need to share a picture but does not have enough information to consider it an answer.

My question is if we could implement this feature in the comment section. And also if this issue has already been raised before.

Apologies if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: At present one can upload a picture and put a link to it in a Comment in the usual way.  I feel this is sufficient for the use case you describe.

Comment: I agree with @hardmath.  Imagine the length of a comment thread which includes, say, 12 textual comments, along with six separate users each posting and image (or two) in a comment field!

Comment: agreed that would ruin the comment section. But what if one is unable to view the images on a different site. what then?

Comment: @TheIntegrator:  Images can be uploaded here (to `imgur`) in a variety of formats that will then be visible by following the link.  See for example, [this image I used in an older Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoSTO.png).

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to insert an image in comments? if the answer is “yes”, then how?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16445)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way around this is to post the graphics into an answer, and then use the imgur link to the photo in the comment.

This is not going to show the image, of course, but it is a start.

In any case, with the "comments are temporary second-class citizens" philosophy, I don't see how such a feature request would be accepted by the SE Overlords.

Comment: So I can't post images like $\ddot \smile$ in comments?

Comment: It's only an image if your MathJax render is an image. :)